# Exercise about algebras for a monad

Tags: category-theory

> The forgetful functor $U:\bf{ Top}\to \bf{Set}$ is a left adjoint. If $I$ denotes its right adjoint,  describe the category of the algebras for the associated monad $T=IU$.

First off, the right adjoint is the functor that sends a topological space $(X,\tau)$ to $(X,\iota)$, where $\iota$ denotes the trivial topology. It follows that $T(X,\tau)=(X,\iota)$, $\eta_X:(X,\tau)\to(X,\iota)$ is (the continuous function with underlying map) the identity on $X$, and $\mu_X:(X,\iota)\to (X,\iota)$ again the identity. I don't understand what are the algebras $((X,\tau),h)$ for this monad, since by the unit law I have that the underlying map of $h$ is the identity on $X$; however this is not continuous as a function $(X,\iota)\to (X,\tau)$. I would say that the continuous functions $(X,\iota)\to (X,\tau)$ are all the (set-theoretic) maps whose image is the closure of a point in $(X,\tau)$. I don't understand if it means that the $T$-algebras does not "add structure" in this case, but "add properties", in the sense that they are not all topological spaces but only the spaces that are the closure of a point, or if I'm just wrong. Thanks for any clarify

Comment: Well, $I$ is fully faithful. In general the monad of an adjunction where the right adjoint is fully faithful will have the property that its algebras do not "add structure" but only "add properties".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $(A,\alpha)$ is an algebra for $T$. Then $A$ is a topological space $(X,\tau)$ and $\alpha\colon T(A)\to A$ is a continuous map from $(X,\iota)$ to $(X,\tau)$, where $\iota$ is the trivial topology on $X$, as in your question.

We also know that $\alpha\circ \eta_A = \text{id}_A$, by the unit diagram. Since $\eta_A$ is the map $T(A) = (X,\iota) \to A = (X,\tau)$ which is the identity on points, and $\text{id}_A$ is also the identity on points, $\alpha$ must be the identity on points as well. Since $\alpha\colon (X,\iota)\to (X,\tau)$ is continuous, it follows that every open set in $\tau$ is open in $\iota$, and hence $\tau$ is the trivial topology.

What we've shown is that if $(A,\alpha)$ is an algebra for $T$, then $A$ is a topological space with the trivial topology, so $T(A) = A$, and $\alpha$ is the identity map. Conversely, it's not hard to check that whenever $A$ is a topological space with the trivial topology, $(A,\text{id}_A)$ is an algebra for $T$. So the algebras for $T$ are exactly the topological spaces with the trivial topology.

This is what's meant by only "adding properties". The base category is the category of topological spaces. A $T$-algebra is not a topological space with extra structure, but rather a certain kind of topological space. Put another way, the category of $T$-algebras is a full subcategory of the category of topological spaces.